# A tag "{% for obj in array %}" não faz o loop e não completa a tabela

Tags: django, django-templates

Olá, pessoal!

Estou tendo um problema para colocar os itens do meu banco de dados em uma tabela na view. Pelo o que eu vi está tudo nos conformes, porém os itens não aparecem na tabela.

Segue o código:

Models

```
from audioop import reverse
from django.db import models


""" Modelo para Produtos """

class ListaProdutos(models.Model):
    nome_produto = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Produto')
    quantidade_produto = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Qntd.')
    custo_venda = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Custo/Venda')
    fornecedor = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Fornecedor')
    data_adicao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True ,verbose_name='Data de Adição')
    nota_produto = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {} {}".format(self.nome_produto, self.quantidade_produto, self.custo_venda, self.fornecedor, self.data_adicao, self.nota_produto)



""" Modelo para Despesas """
class ListaDespesas(models.Model):

    GASTO = (
        ('Semanal', 'Semanal'),
        ('Mensal', 'Mensal'),
        ('Esporádico', 'Esporádico'),
    )

    nome_despesa = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Despesas')
    quantidade_despesa = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Qntd.')
    custo = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Custo')
    tipo_gasto = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices= GASTO, verbose_name='Tipo de Gasto')
    data_atualizacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True ,verbose_name='Data de Atualização')
    nota_despesa = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {} {}".format(self.nome_despesa, self.quantidade_despesa, self.custo, self.tipo_gasto, self.data_atualizacao, self.nota_despesa)
```

Views

```
from dataclasses import fields
import json
from unittest import result
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ListaDespesas, ListaProdutos
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.contrib import messages





""" Configurações do CRUD da parte de Despesa FIXA e VARIÁVEL """


def despesa_List(request):
    despesa_list = ListaDespesas.objects.all()
    return render(request, "paginas/gastos.html", {'despesas': despesa_list })


#----------# Função ADD Despesa #----------#


def add_despesa(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        if request.POST.get('nome_despesa') \
            and request.POST.get('quantidade_despesa') \
            and request.POST.get('custo') \
            and request.POST.get('tipo_gasto') \
            and request.POST.get('data_atualizacao') \
            or request.POST.get('nota_despesa'):
            
            despesa = ListaDespesas()
            despesa.nome_despesa = request.POST.get('nome_despesa')
            despesa.quantidade_despesa = request.POST.get('quantidade_despesa')
            despesa.custo = request.POST.get('custo')
            despesa.tipo_gasto = request.POST.get('tipo_gasto')
            despesa.data_atualizacao = request.POST.get('data_atualizacao')
            despesa.nota_despesa = request.POST.get('nota_despesa')
            despesa.save()
            messages.success(request, "Despesa adicionada com sucesso!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/gastos")
    else:
        return render(request, 'cadastro \\ add-despesa.html')


#----------# Função VIEW Despesa #----------#


def despesa(request, despesas_id):
    despesa =  ListaDespesas.objects.get(id = despesas_id)
    if despesa != None:
        return render(request, "cadastro \\ edit-despesa.html", {'despesa':despesa})


#----------# Função EDIT Despesa #----------#

def edit_despesa(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        despesa = ListaDespesas.objects.get(id = request.POST.get('id'))
        if despesa != None:
            despesa.nome_despesa = request.POST.get('nome_despesa')
            despesa.quantidade_despesa = request.POST.get('quantidade_despesa')
            despesa.custo = request.POST.get('custo')
            despesa.tipo_gasto = request.POST.get('tipo_gasto')
            despesa.data_atualizacao = request.POST.get('data_atualizacao')
            despesa.nota_despesa = request.POST.get('nota_despesa')
            despesa.save()
            messages.success(request, "Despesa atualizada com sucesso!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/gastos")
            

#----------# Função DELETE Despesa #----------#

def delete_despesa(request, despesa_id):
    despesa = ListaDespesas.objects.get(id = despesa_id)
    despesa.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Despesa deletada com sucesso!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/gastos")










def estoqueList(request):
    qs = ListaProdutos.objects.all()
    return render(request, "paginas/estoque.html", {'object_list': qs})


def addProduct(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product = ListaProdutos()
        product.nome_produto = request.POST.get('nome_produto')
        product.quantidade_produto = request.POST.get('quantidade_produto')
        product.custo_venda = request.POST.get('custo_venda')
        product.fornecedor = request.POST.get('fornecedor')
        product.data_adicao = request.POST.get('data_adicao')
        product.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/estoque')
    else:
        return render(request, 'cadastro\\add.html')


def viewProduct(request, product_id):
    product = ListaProdutos.objects.get(id=product_id)
    if product != None:
        return render(request, 'cadastro\\edit.html', {'produto': product})


def editProduct(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product = ListaProdutos.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('id'))
        if product != None:
            product.nome_produto = request.POST.get('nome_produto')
            product.quantidade_produto = request.POST.get('quantidade_produto')
            product.custo_venda = request.POST.get('custo_venda')
            product.fornecedor = request.POST.get('fornecedor')
            product.data_adicao = request.POST.get('data_adicao')
            product.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/estoque')


def delProduct(request, product_id):
    product = ListaProdutos.objects.get(id=product_id)
    product.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/estoque')












""" Configuração da views para Despesas """


def lista_despesa(request):
    lista_despesa = ListaDespesas.objects.all()
    return render(request, "paginas/gastos.html", {"despesa": lista_despesa})


def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'


def checkProduto(request):
    if is_ajax:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            produtos = list(ListaProdutos.objects.all().values())
            return JsonResponse({'produtos': produtos})

        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Invalid request'}, status=400)

    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid request')


def checkProduto2(request):
    result = ListaProdutos.objects.all()
    serialized_data = json.dumps(list(result), default=str)

    return JsonResponse({'PRODUTOS': serialized_data})

    # return HttpResponse(serialized_data)
```

HTLM com a tag

```
{% extends 'paginas/modelo.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block titulo %}
<title>Gastos</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'imagens/game-solid-26.png' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block conteudo %}

<div class="home_content">
    <div class="conteudo_pagina">

        <div class="container">

            <br><br><br>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addModal">
                Adicione Despesa Variável
            </button>
                
            <br><br><br>  

            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tabela_despesa" style="text-align: center ;">
                <thead class="table-success">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Despesa</th>
                        <th>Quantidade</th>
                        <th>Custo</th>
                        <th>Tipo de Gasto</th>
                        <th>Data de Atualização</th>
                        <th>Editar</th>
                        <th>Deletar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                {% for despesa in despesas %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ despesa.nome_despesa }}</td>
                    <td>{{ despesa.quantidade_despesa }}</td>
                    <td>{{ despesa.custo }}</td>
                    <td>{{ despesa.tipo_gasto}}</td>
                    <td>{{ despesa.data_atualizacao | date:'d/m/Y (H:i)'}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-sucess text-center" title="Editar Despesa">
                            <i class='bx bx-edit'></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary text-center" title="Deletar Despesa">
                            <i class='bx bx-folder-minus'></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>

        </div>

        <!-- Tags de para incluir Modal de add e del de Despesas -->

        {% include 'cadastro/add-despesa.html' %}









    </div>
</div>




{% endblock %}
```

Imagem da tabela

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApyCm.png)

Answer (score -1):

Olá, pelo que pude observar no seu código nos trechos a seguir:

Antes - view

```
def despesa_List(request):
    despesa_list = ListaDespesas.objects.all()
    return render(request, "paginas/gastos.html", {'despesas': despesa_list })
```

Depois - View

```
def despesa_List(request):
    despesa_list = ListaDespesas.objects.all()
    return render(request, "paginas/gastos.html", {'despesa_list': despesa_list})
```

Faça igual ao de cima na View.

No html template, no For faça a seguinte correção na condição

```
{% for despesa in despesa_list %}
```

**Encontrei algo redundante na sua view você tem duas função para retornar a mesmos dados? Não faz muito sentido.**

```
""" Configurações do CRUD da parte de Despesa FIXA e VARIÁVEL """


def despesa_List(request):
    despesa_list = ListaDespesas.objects.all()
    return render(request, "paginas/gastos.html", {'despesas': despesa_list })

""" Configuração da views para Despesas """


def lista_despesa(request):
    lista_despesa = ListaDespesas.objects.all()
    return render(request, "paginas/gastos.html", {"despesa": lista_despesa})
```

Para conseguir uma analise melhor e confirmar de forma fácil se os dados estão sendo realmente passados nessa view faça a instalação do [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)